# Shopify Application proxies not working with the custom domain

Tags: php, shopify, shopify-app

I have added application proxies in my app as shown in the documentation [Application proxies - front end development](https://help.shopify.com/api/guides/application-proxies), its working fine with the default Shopify domain (Ex: example.myshopify.com) but not working with the custom domain (Ex: example.com), showing 404.

How can we run it for custom domain too?

Comment: Could you provide more details? What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: My app is installed in both the stores: https://anntest.myshopify.com/apps/webpushsdk/fmc-sw.js & https://www.privateprize.com/apps/webpushsdk/fmc-sw.js first url is running second one is showing 404 not found.